# Is there a location settings change listener for react native?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am trying figure out how to listen to event when the user turns on or off the location in the settings. I tried `navigator.geolocation.watchposition` but didn't have much success, since it does not listen to the respective event.

Comment: isnt it what you need:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition

Comment: nope since it does not listen to event when the user turns the gps on or off, it only listens to location change event

Comment: Hii , I think u are looking for 
https://github.com/rmrs/react-native-settings#listen-to-setting-change-event-when-applicable

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save react-native-location
react-native link

var React = require('react-native');
var { DeviceEventEmitter } = React;
var { RNLocation: Location } = require('NativeModules');

Location.getAuthorizationStatus(function(authorization) {
   //authorization is a string which is either "authorizedAlways",
   //"authorizedWhenInUse", "denied", "notDetermined" or "restricted"
});

Location.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
Location.startUpdatingLocation();
Location.setDistanceFilter(5.0);

var subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
    'locationUpdated',
    (location) => {
        /* Example location returned
        {
          coords: {
            speed: -1,
            longitude: -0.1337,
            latitude: 51.50998,
            accuracy: 5,
            heading: -1,
            altitude: 0,
            altitudeAccuracy: -1
          },
          timestamp: 1446007304457.029
        }
        */
    }
);
```

Refer to [this site](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location) for more details.

Comment: This would useful if I wanted to listen for the location update, which is not the case. I only need to handle gps on/off events... Besides it is only module for ios... :(

Comment: Hi @user3470622, did you find the solution? I am facing with the same problem!

Comment: @user3470622 Did you find the solution? Even I am facing with same issue.

Comment: @SmoggeR_js Did you find the solution? Even I am facing with same issue

Comment: I am facing same issue.

Comment: You can use react-native-background-geolocation to get updates

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-setting

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const locationListener = SystemSetting.addLocationListener(
      (locationEnabled) => console.log(locationEnabled),
    );

    return () => SystemSetting.removeListener(locationListener);
  }, []);
```