# Is there an official or library function to verify the changes in the states and GPS permissions in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, geolocation, gps

To guarantee the correct operation of the application that I am developing, it is necessary to know the current status and permissions of the GPS at all times.

Reviewing the official documentation of native react, note that there is no natural way to verify changes in GPS statuses using the official library (Geolocation). Therefore I decided to look for third-party libraries that would allow me to verify the changes, among which I found:

1. react-native-gps-state
2. react-native-connectivity-status

Both libraries have small problems on Android and do not report changes with the sensor status and permissions.

Some programmers use the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` as a strategy to obtain the changes in the states using a code similar to:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    //Processing the enabled status of the GPS
  },
  error => {
  //Processing the disabled status of the GPS
},
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
);
```

It is evident that this solution is not the most optimal (could be presented TIME_OUT in most cases) apart it is necessary to implement additional code to check the status at all times.

Comment: `it is necessary to know the current status and permissions of the GPS at all times.`. Why not use a library that checks for permissions? e.g. react-native-permissions (or Permissions module if using Expo)

`Permissions.check('location').then(response => {
      // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)
    })`

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273952/is-there-a-location-settings-change-listener-for-react-native/66116732#66116732

Answer (score 0):

React Native has `Geolocation` as built-in library, you can use `watchPosition` function to check for location changes, it also has options for specifying timeout.
You can find the whole doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation)

Comment: Is there any method that a listener can be added to verify if the GPS is turned on or off?